# Iterate over an IQueryable without calling ToList()

Tags: c#, database, linq, foreach, iqueryable

I have a DB used for a production line. It has an Orders table, and Ordertracker table, an Item table, and an Itemtracker table.

Both Orders and Items have many-to-many relationships with status. The tracker tables resolves these relationships in such a way that an item can have multiple entries in the tracker - each with a particular status.

I tried to upload a picture of the tables to make things clearer but alas, I don't have enough points yet :C

I need to find items whose last status in the Itemtracker table meets a condition, either '3' or '0'.

I then need to get the first one of these items.

The steps I am using to accomplish this are as follows:

1. Get all the Orders which have a certain status.
2. Get all the Items in that Order.
3. Get all the Items whose last status was = 0 or 3.
4. Get the first of these items.

My code is as follows:

```
    public ITEM GetFirstItemFailedOrNotInProductionFromCurrentOrder()
    {

        var firstOrder = GetFirstOrderInProductionAndNotCompleted();

        var items = ERPContext.ITEM.Where(i => i.OrderID == firstOrder.OrderID) as IQueryable<ITEM>;

        if (CheckStatusOfItems(items) != null)
        {
            var nextItem = CheckStatusOfItems(items);

            return nextItem ;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private ITEM CheckStatusOfItems(IQueryable<ITEM> items)
    {
        List<ITEM> listOfItemsToProduce = new List<ITEM>();

        foreach (ITEM item in items.ToList())
        {

           var lastStatusOfItem = ERPContext.ITEMTRACKER.Where(it => it.ItemID == item.ItemID)
                                                        .OrderByDescending(it => it.ItemTrackerID).FirstOrDefault();

            if (lastStatusOfItem.ItemStatus == (int)ItemStatus.Failed || lastStatusOfItem.ItemStatus == (int)ItemStatus.Confirmed)
            {
                listOfItemsToProduce.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return listOfItemsToProduce.FirstOrDefault();

    }
```

Now, this all works fine and returns what I need but I'm aware that this might not be the best approach.  As it is now my IQueryable collection of items will never contain more than 6 items - but if it could grow larger, then calling ToList() on the IQueryable and iterating over the results in-memory would probably not be a good idea.

Is there a better way to iterate through the IQueryable items to fetch out the items that have a certain status as their latest status without calling ToList() and foreaching through the results?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looping through an IQueryable would be super slow if you are lazy loading the info.  Each loop then becomes a new query.  Does `ITEMTRACKER` not have an association with `ITEM` in your model?

Comment: Btw, you should cache the result of `CheckStatusOfItems` into a variable and then check the variable for null. Otherwise you're calling it twice and executing your queries twice as well. That said you could collapse the whole first method to `var firstOrder=... ; var items=... ; return CheckStatusOfItems(items);` since if it's not null you're returning the result and if it IS null you're returning null which is consequently the same thing as returning the (null) result

Comment: Yes, I think so,  ITEMTRACKER is the table that joins the ITEM table to the ITEMSTATUS table. ItemID and OrderID are the PK in ITEM.  ItemID, OrderID and ItemStatus are FK's in ITEMTRACKER - the PK is ItemTrackerID.  Any suggestions how to tackle this? Thanks

Comment: Also, more generally: if you only wish to return the first match in a collection, don't loop through the entire list and add all matching items to another list and then finally return the first item of *that* collection... Just return the first item that meets your condition *when you encounter it*, followed by a `return null` after the loop

Comment: Noted! Thanks pinkfloydx33

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using LINQ query syntax, you can build declaratively a single query pretty much the same way you wrote the imperative iteration. `foreach` translates to `from`, `var` to `let` and `if` to `where`:

```
private ITEM CheckStatusOfItems(IQueryable<ITEM> items)
{
    var query =
        from item in items
        let lastStatusOfItem = ERPContext.ITEMTRACKER
            .Where(it => it.ItemID == item.ItemID)
            .OrderByDescending(it => it.ItemTrackerID)
            .FirstOrDefault()
        where (lastStatusOfItem.ItemStatus == (int)ItemStatus.Failed || lastStatusOfItem.ItemStatus == (int)ItemStatus.Confirmed)
        select item;

    return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

or alternatively using `from` instead of `let` and `Take(1)` instead of `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
private ITEM CheckStatusOfItems(IQueryable<ITEM> items)
{
    var query =
        from item in items
        from lastStatusOfItem in ERPContext.ITEMTRACKER
            .Where(it => it.ItemID == item.ItemID)
            .OrderByDescending(it => it.ItemTrackerID)
            .Take(1)
        where (lastStatusOfItem.ItemStatus == (int)ItemStatus.Failed || lastStatusOfItem.ItemStatus == (int)ItemStatus.Confirmed)
        select item;

    return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: The `Take(1)` is the solution.  `FirstOrDefault()` always causes problems.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you - so if I understand it correctly - the Take(1) solution allows the query to execute in the DB as an expression tree rather than the ToList() approach which required the items collection to be returned first?

Comment: You are welcome. Both ways would generate and execute single SQL query (`SELECT TOP 1 ...`). The key point is to keep the whole thing `IQueryable<T>` as much as possible (like above `query` variable) and execute it once at the end.

Comment: Extremely helpful.  Have tried to upvote your answer but I don't appear to have enough points for my vote to register.

Comment: Not a problem at all, glad it helped :) But if you wish, you could always accept and answer to your own question - no rep is needed for that :)